# Google Map API v3 parsing xml and getting elements by tag name

Tags: google-maps-api-3, xml-parsing

I'm having some problems in parsing my xml to be overlayed in google map as markers, first off, I have an XML file like this

```
<root>
```

`<weather>`

`<city>city_name</city>`

`<level>1</level>`

`<data>weather_data</data>`

`<lat>-6.211544</lat>`

`<lon>106.845172</lon>`

```
<elevation>13.41</elevation>
```

`</weather>`

```
</root>
```

as you can see I contain the necessary data inside one tag, not attribute, problem is, in V2 I used GDownloadUrl and GXml parse and getelementsbytagname method works. In V3 it seems I can't use GDownloadUrl, and all the examples I've seen on the internet uses attribute parsing. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the source for geoxml3 (either the [polys branch](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/source/browse/branches/polys/geoxml3.js) or the [kmz branch](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/source/browse/branches/kmz/geoxml3.js)); the nodeValue function, this is from the kmz branch, the polys branch is slightly different, either will work:

```
/**
 * Extract the text value of a DOM node, with leading and trailing whitespace trimmed.
 *
 * @param {Element} node XML node/element.
 * @param {Any} delVal Default value if the node doesn't exist.
 * @return {String|Null}
 */
geoXML3.nodeValue = function(node, defVal) {
  var retStr="";
  if (!node) {
    return (typeof defVal === 'undefined' || defVal === null) ? null : defVal;
  }
  if(node.nodeType==3||node.nodeType==4||node.nodeType==2){
     retStr+=node.nodeValue;
  }else if(node.nodeType==1||node.nodeType==9||node.nodeType==11){
    for(var i=0;i<node.childNodes.length;++i){
      retStr+=arguments.callee(node.childNodes[i]);
    }
  }
  return retStr;
}
```

Another option is [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/scripts/Gxml.js) implementation of the two Gxml functions from v2.

Comment: oh so GXml does not implemented in v3. Thanks for the help, I'll try this method while restructuring the XML into v3 friendly form.

Comment: I'm not sure what "v3 friendly form" means. v3 doesn't support any xml parsing natively, that has to be done in your code or an external library.