# Google Maps, Ajax XML data

Tags: ajax, xml, google-maps, xmlhttprequest

I am learning to access data from an XML file and place on a Google map but keep getting the error: 'TypeError: xml is undefined
http://gm.boomeranginternet.co.uk/Default3.aspx
Line 138'

Can anyone see why this error is occurring?

[All code is on this example](http://gm.boomeranginternet.co.uk/Default3.aspx)

```
var map;

    var Data = [];                           // this array stores all data           
    var viewportMarkersKS2 = [];
    var viewportMarkersP16 = [];
    var viewportMarkersHealthcare = [];
    var KS2MarkersVisible = document.getElementById('Checkbox1');
    var P16MarkersVisible = document.getElementById('Checkbox2');
    var HealthcareMarkersVisible = document.getElementById('Checkbox3');
    var infoWindow;
    var handle1, handle2;
    var iconBlue = 'icons/blue-dot.png';
    var iconGreen = 'icons/green-dot.png';
    var iconPink = 'icons/pink-dot.png';
    //var zoomLevel = map.getZoom();

    // property and map center
    var iniLat = 51.401997;
    var iniLon = -1.276934;
    var iniZoom = 15;
    var ResetZoom = 13;
    var maxZoom = 12;
    var propertyLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(iniLat, iniLon);

    function initialize() {

        // change map size dependent on useragent
        detectBrowser()

        // map options
        var mapOptions = {
            center: propertyLatLng,
            zoom: iniZoom
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);




        //********************************************************************************************************************
        //********************************************************************************************************************
        //**********************************************                         *********************************************
        //**********************************************    SELECTED PROPERTY    *********************************************
        //**********************************************                         *********************************************
        //********************************************************************************************************************
        //********************************************************************************************************************

        // add the property to the map
        var propertyIcon = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: propertyLatLng
        });




        // infoWindows
        var infoWindowContent = '11 Derwent Road<br />Thatcham<br />Berkshire<br />RG19 3UT';

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: infoWindowContent
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(propertyIcon, 'click', function () {
            infowindow.open(map, propertyIcon);
        });


        // add markers to the map
        propertyIcon.setMap(map);





        // when user drags the map or zooms in/out, update list of airports in range
        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', function () { showGetResultXml() });
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function () { showGetResultXml() });
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () { showGetResultXml() });


    }





    function showGetResultXml() {
        var result = null;
        var scriptUrl = "http://gm.boomeranginternet.co.uk/xml/amenitydata.xml";
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: scriptUrl,
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'xml',
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                result = data;
                var xml = data.responseXML;
                var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("Row");

                for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                    var name = markers[i].getAttribute("SchoolName");
                    var address = markers[i].getAttribute("Address1");
                    var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
                    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("Coordinates")));

                    var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
                    var icon = customIcons[type] || {};

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
                    {
                        map: map,
                        position: point,
                        icon: iconBlue
                    });

                    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
                }
            },
            error: function onXmlError() {
                alert("An Error has occurred.");
            }
        });







        function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                infoWindow.setContent(html);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        }

        return result;
    }



    function detectBrowser() {
        var useragent = navigator.userAgent;
        var mapdiv = document.getElementById("map-canvas");

        if (useragent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1 || useragent.indexOf('Android') != -1) {
            mapdiv.style.width = '100%';
            mapdiv.style.height = '100%';
        } else {
            mapdiv.style.width = '100%';
        }
    }





    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<AmenityData>
  <Row>
    <LANumber>869</LANumber>
    <EstablishmentNumber>4034</EstablishmentNumber>
    <SchoolName>John O&amp;#39;Gaunt School</SchoolName>
    <Address1>Priory Road</Address1>
    <Town>Hungerford</Town>
    <Postcode>RG17 0AN</Postcode>
    <Coordinates>51.405190, -1.514791</Coordinates>
    <lat>51.405190</lat>
    <long>-1.514791</long>
    <TelNumber>01488 682400</TelNumber>
    <Type>CY</Type>
    <Age>61</Age>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <LANumber>872</LANumber>
    <EstablishmentNumber>4051</EstablishmentNumber>
    <SchoolName>The Bulmershe School</SchoolName>
    <Address1>Chequers Way</Address1>
    <Address2>Woodley</Address2>
    <Town>Reading</Town>
    <Postcode>RG5 3EL</Postcode>
    <Coordinates>51.454231, -0.917519</Coordinates>
    <lat>51.454231</lat>
    <long>-0.917519</long>
    <TelNumber>0118 9353353</TelNumber>
    <Type>CY</Type>
    <Age>170</Age>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <LANumber>872</LANumber>
    <EstablishmentNumber>4049</EstablishmentNumber>
    <SchoolName>The Emmbrook School</SchoolName>
    <Address1>Emmbrook Road</Address1>
    <Town>Wokingham</Town>
    <Postcode>RG41 1JP</Postcode>
    <Coordinates>51.421683, -0.851670</Coordinates>
    <lat>51.421683</lat>
    <long>-0.851670</long>
    <TelNumber>0118 9784406</TelNumber>
    <Type>CY</Type>
    <Age>219</Age>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <LANumber>870</LANumber>
    <EstablishmentNumber>4020</EstablishmentNumber>
    <SchoolName>Highdown School and Sixth Form Centre</SchoolName>
    <Address1>Surley Row</Address1>
    <Address2>Emmer Green</Address2>
    <Town>Reading</Town>
    <Postcode>RG4 8LR</Postcode>
    <Coordinates>51.481701, -0.975611</Coordinates>
    <lat>51.481701</lat>
    <long>-0.975611</long>
    <TelNumber>0118 9015800</TelNumber>
    <Type>ACC</Type>
    <Age>273</Age>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <LANumber>869</LANumber>
    <EstablishmentNumber>7005</EstablishmentNumber>
    <SchoolName>Mary Hare School</SchoolName>
    <Address1>Arlington Manor</Address1>
    <Address2>Snelsmore Common</Address2>
    <Town>Newbury</Town>
    <Postcode>RG14 3BQ</Postcode>
    <Coordinates>51.437105, -1.329385</Coordinates>
    <lat>51.437105</lat>
    <long>-1.329385</long>
    <TelNumber>01635 244200</TelNumber>
    <Type>NMSS</Type>
    <Age>70</Age>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <LANumber>872</LANumber>
    <EstablishmentNumber>6001</EstablishmentNumber>
    <SchoolName>Bearwood College</SchoolName>
    <Address1>Bearwood</Address1>
    <Town>Wokingham</Town>
    <Postcode>RG41 5BG</Postcode>
    <Coordinates>51.415843, -0.883741</Coordinates>
    <lat>51.415843</lat>
    <long>-0.883741</long>
    <TelNumber>0118 9748300</TelNumber>
    <Type>IND</Type>
    <Age>77</Age>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <LANumber>867</LANumber>
    <EstablishmentNumber>4061</EstablishmentNumber>
    <SchoolName>Easthampstead Park Community School</SchoolName>
    <Address1>Ringmead</Address1>
    <Town>Bracknell</Town>
    <Postcode>RG12 8FS</Postcode>
    <Coordinates>51.398508, -0.782719</Coordinates>
    <lat>51.398508</lat>
    <long>-0.782719</long>
    <TelNumber>01344 304567</TelNumber>
    <Type>CY</Type>
    <Age>125</Age>
  </Row>
</AmenityData>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please post the (relevant) code in the question itself, not just a link to a page which will change or go away when the problem gets addressed (the link is helpful, but will not be useful once your issue is fixed). See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You should probably also post a sample of the XML as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like there is no `.responseXML` property of `data`.

Change this:

```
success: function(data) {
            result = data;
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("Row");
```

To:

```
success: function(data) {
            var markers = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("Row");
```

Comment: Thanks, that did get rid of that error, but nothing is showing on the map. I wrote a value to the console log 'markers[i].getAttribute("SchoolName")' but it is returning null. So doesn't seem to be getting the XML values.

Comment: `<SchoolName>` is not an attribute of `<Row>`, it is an element inside the `<Row>` element.

Comment: Ah, should have done some research into XML a bit more....got there with - markers[i].getElementsByTagName("SchoolName")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue

Comment: related question: [Google Map API v3 parsing xml and getting elements by tag name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13657364/google-map-api-v3-parsing-xml-and-getting-elements-by-tag-name/13659569#13659569)

Comment: related question: [Google Maps API: Markers from XML file not being displayed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27024983/google-maps-api-markers-from-xml-file-not-being-displayed/27027097#27027097)

Comment: Thanks all very handy, will look into that a bit more.